# What should I use to check if user's input is the same as generated random numbers?

Tags: c

My code generates 5 random numbers and I want the user to guess these numbers after 5 seconds of flashing it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

main()
{
    menuchoose1();
    
}

int menuchoose1(){
    int menu1choose;
    int score=0;
    int mode,i,j;
    int n=5;
    printf("1.Continuous Mode\n");
    printf("2.Stage Mode\n");
    scanf("%d",&menu1choose);
    
    switch(menu1choose){
    int answers;
            case 1:
                srand(time(NULL)* getpid() );
                int a[5];
                unique(a,5,10,99);
                int i;
                printf("You have 5 seconds to remember these numbers\n");               
                for(i=0;i<5;i++)
                printf("%d\t",a[i]);
                sleep(5);
                system("cls");
                scanf("%d",&answers);
                if(answers==a[i]){
                    printf("Correct");
                }else
                    printf("Incorrect");
                break;
        }
    return;
}

void unique(int array[], int length, int min, int max){
    
    int new_randomnum;
    bool unique;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        do{
            new_randomnum = (rand()%(max - min + 1 )) + min;
            unique = true;
            int j;
            for(j=0;j<0;j++)
            if(array[j] == new_randomnum) unique = false;
        }while(!unique);
        array[i] = new_randomnum;
    }
}
```

I've tried using scanf but it always ends up incorrect and generating it one by one then checking it one by one would be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this program produces [a ton of compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/zhdWeGzfb).  I strongly suggest you get in the habit of enabling warnings, and never ignore them!  For instance, you are missing a lot of headers and forward declarations. If your compiler does not give you those warnings, then you should consider switching to a better one.

Below I will only mention those bugs that do not trigger warnings.

```
       srand(time(NULL)* getpid() );
```

If you call `srand` on each round of the game, you risk getting the same sequence of numbers again.  Just call it once at the start of the program, e.g. in `main`.

```
            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
                printf("%d\t",a[i]);
            sleep(5);
            system("cls");
            scanf("%d",&answers);
            if(answers==a[i]){
                printf("Correct");
            }else
                printf("Incorrect");
            break;
```

I fixed the indentation to emphasize the bug.  The `if(answers == a[i])` is after the loop and therefore `i` always has the value 5 when it is reached, which is out of bounds for the array `a`, causing undefined behavior.  You probably want the code to get and check the user's answer to be in a loop of its own.

```
        for(j=0;j<0;j++)
            if(array[j] == new_randomnum)
                unique = false;
```

The `j<0` condition means this loop will never execute.  You probably meant `j<i`.

Answer (score 0):

Detail on one part of OP's code.

`srand(time(NULL)* getpid() );` is a weak way to initialize the random number generator.

Example: if either of the least significant bits of `time(NULL)` or `getpid()` are 0, the product with have a least significant bit of zero.  Thus that bit has a 75% change of being 0.

Instead, call `srand()` once, before the loops and use the 2 function calls like: `(unsigned) time(NULL) ^ getpid()`.  By using `^`, the bits will not get biased as discussed above.